# Iphone iAp [response.products count] is empty

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase

Thats the problem - i have no products in my response for the iAp products.
I've read many themes about it here, at stackoverflow, plus here: 
http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/
And its all "YES". But it still wont work.
My appid iAps is ON, my provisioning new, my iapps connected to the App, and Cleared for sale, so... 
Please, help.

PS. All the identifiers, that i've sent, returns me in the response.invalidProductIdentifiers array

PPS. itunes connect account was linked in Australia. (But in the account all stores was included for selling)

```
  - (void)sendProductRequest:(NSString *)ID {
    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:ID]]; 
    request.delegate = self;
    [APPDELEGATE increaseNetworkUseCount];
    [request start]; 
}

- (void)sendProductRequestForCourseTests {
    [self sendProductRequest:@"au.bla.blabla.blablabla.inapptesting"]; // for example. 100% matching with my productID at itunes connect
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response { 
    for (int i = 0; i < [response.invalidProductIdentifiers count]; i ++) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [response.invalidProductIdentifiers objectAtIndex:i]); // here we have my Product id
    }

    DbgLog(@"Products count in received responce: %d", [response.products count]); // here i've got Zero!
    SKProduct* product = [response.products count] > 0 ? [response.products objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    if (product) {
        //NSString *storeProductID = myProduct.productIdentifier;

        //SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:storeProductID];
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
        DbgLog(@"Payment request sent for product with id: %@", product.productIdentifier);
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    } else {
        [APPDELEGATE decreaseNetworkUseCount];
        for (id <IAPManagerObserver> observer in observers) {
            [observer IAPManager:self didFinishSuccessfully:NO withTransaction:nil];
        }
    }
    [request autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Please provide some further code examples for our edification.

Answer (score 2):

check below points,

1. Does your project’s .plist Bundle ID match your App ID
2. Are you using the full product ID when when making an SKProductRequest

This is the normal scenario issue. Please check this items, it should resolve the issue.

Comment: its OK with that, for example:

My appID: "au.bla.blabla.inapptesting"
My productID 1: "au.bla.blabla.blablabla.iap1"
My productID 2: "tests"
i've trying to send productID1, & productID2, & in all cases i get
response.invalidProductIdentifiers with my productID

I have experience with working with iAps, its my 5th or 6th application with iApps, but... i get that damn mistake :(

Comment: It was number 2 for me that you suggested that you make sure you send the product identifies. I have been looking at this for ages.. THANKS!